# How to fetch the DOM elements and javascript variables in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am writing a PHP script to dynamically create table in MySQL based on user's input for number of columns and the column names. I am stuck in accessing the DOM elements and the Javascript variables in my PHP code.
Here is my complete code for the same:

```
<?php

    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    function createInputFields(){

    var x = document.getElementById('n-cols');
    var n = x.value;

    if(x.selectedIndex == 0){
        alert('Choose a valid index');
    }

document.getElementById('main').innerHTML ='<br>';

for(var i = 0; i < n;i++){
       document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += '<input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"column\" > <select> <option>Integer</option> <option>Varchar</option>  </select><br>';
    }

    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML+='<input type=\"submit\"   onClick=\"post()\" Value=\"Create Table\">';
}
</script>";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    #head-text{
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 250%;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="head-text">Snippt</h1>
    <div class="main-content">

    <frameset>
        <form>
        <select name="n-cols" id="n-cols"     onchange="createInputFields()">
            <option>Number of columns</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <div id="main">

    </div>


    </frameset>

    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

How to get the number of columns and column names in php code that table can be created in MySQL using php script?

Comment: use ajax to pass javascript variable contents to php

Comment: But the tables are being created based on user's choice so i will not be aware of the column numbers initially. So how should my AJAX code be? @SalluSalman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement asynchronous calls with AJAX in your code.
See https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp

Comment: Thanx a lot! That was really helpful.. @Ray